Disable other-half popup when view splitting
Whenever I use left/right view splitting, a popup is displayed, prompting me which window to put on the other half of the screen.
For example, when I do SuperLeft while Emacs is focused, the window snaps to the left half of the screen, as desired, but then I get this popup prompting what to put on the right half of my screen (circled in red):

(This popup also disables screenshots until it is dismissed, so that's nice.)
How can I disable this prompt-to-fill-other-half function entirely?

The Popup that you see is the Tiling popup
To disable it simply use Settings, Ubuntu Desktop and under Enhanced Tiling turn off Tilling Popup.

